# Android foreground service gets killed on Huawei device

Tags: android

My app is like a tracker. It saves user locations, then sends it to server.
I made this server foreground and sticky. On samsung s4 everything works fine, but on huawei honor 4c service gets killed as fast as i lock screen. Moreover, methods like onDestroy() are not called. If i add app to "Protected apps" it lives more, but nearly 30-45 mins. Is there a way to keep my service alive? Or is there a way to solve my problem without foreground service? I searched tons of posts about this problem, but didnt find solution.

Here is my service

```
public class LocationService extends Service {

    private static final long TIME_BETWEEN_LOCATION_SEND_IN_MILLIS = 60 * 1000;
    private static final long TIME_BETWEEN_LOCATION_UPDATES = 10 * 1000;

    private List<Location> locations;

    private int NOTIFICATION_ID = 31337;

    private boolean isAlreadyRunning = false;
    public boolean Continue = true;

    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        GoogleApiClient.Builder builder = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getApplicationContext());
        googleApiClient = builder
            .addConnectionCallbacks(new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
                @Override
                public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
                    Log.wtf("lol", "connected");
                    LocationRequest locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
                    locationRequest.setInterval(TIME_BETWEEN_LOCATION_UPDATES);
                    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(TIME_BETWEEN_LOCATION_UPDATES);
                    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

                    //noinspection MissingPermission
                    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                        googleApiClient, locationRequest, new LocationListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                                locations.add(location);
                            }
                        });
                }

                @Override
                public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
                    Log.wtf("lol", "connection suspended");
                }
            })
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onConnectionFailed(
                    @NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult
                ) {
                    Log.wtf("lol", "connection Failed");
                }
            })
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
        locations = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        Log.wtf("lol","service onlow");
    }

    @Override
    public void onTrimMemory(int level) {
        super.onTrimMemory(level);
        Log.wtf("lol","service ontrim");
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
        Log.wtf("lol","service ontaskremoved");
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.wtf("lol", "service OnStartCommand");
        if (!isAlreadyRunning) {
            Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            resultIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            resultIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
            PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                this,
                333,
                resultIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            );


            NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setContentTitle("Title")
                    .setContentText("Explanation!")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
                    .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
            Notification notification = builder.build();
            startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
            googleApiClient.connect();
            isAlreadyRunning = true;

            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (locations.size() > 0) {
                        sendLocationsAndClearList();
                    }
                    if(Continue){
                        handler.postDelayed(this,TIME_BETWEEN_LOCATION_SEND_IN_MILLIS);
                    }
                }
            },TIME_BETWEEN_LOCATION_SEND_IN_MILLIS);
        }
        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.wtf("lol", "service onDestroy");
        Continue = false;
        googleApiClient.disconnect();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You also have to create a CPU wake lock. The CPU can tear down to a low power mode which will stop your app process. It may resume if the CPU powers up again for some reason.

Have a look for the WAKE LOCK topic in the Android documentation.